# Prevent HTML5 audio buffering entire mp3 when paused

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I see that the HTML5 audio element buffers some of an MP3 when I click play, however when I call `pause()`, it then downloads the entire file. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is up to the browser implementation. Buffering is not defined in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-audio-element). Your only option is to remove and regenerate the audio element.

Answer (score 0):

Buffering is done per browser, there is a hack way of doing this by removing the src element (change it to an empty string) on pause, and resuming once the play button is clicked again. This is probably the closest you'll get and may cause problems in a variety of browsers as this is a hack way of doing this.